# UTF-8 without signature vs UTF-8 with signature

Tags: c#, utf-8, utf

Using visual studio 2005 text file generating with UTF-8 with signature.
I need without signature.

Comment: Do you mean 'Save As' in the IDE, or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Encoding.UTF8`, you could use [`new UTF8Encoding(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).